# Preparing Data to Plot in d3.js from Ruby on Rails Database

Tags: hash, ruby-on-rails-3.1, d3.js

I have a column in a database with responses to a dropdown "referral source" question. I am querying that and returning a hash:

```
Clients.count(:all, :group => :referral_source)
```

Which results in the following hash:

```
{"Internet search (e.g., Google)?"=>26, 
 "Personal referral (e.g., friend or family)"=>23, 
 "Other"=>11, ""=>51, 
 "Listserv (e.g., neighborhood listserv)"=>5,
 "Walk by"=>5}
```

In the view, I'd like like to plot those results as a bar chart with d3.js. I found this nice with a chart that looks exactly as I would like my chart to look. My problem is the example uses CSV data.

How can I get my data into the format this example uses straight out of rails. In other words, I would like my data to look like an array of objects to pass to javascript in the view:

```
var data = [ {"Name": "Internet search (e.g., Google)?", "Count": 26},
             {"Name": "Personal referral (e.g., friend or family)", "Count": 23},
             ... ]
```

How do I modify that hash (or query) to get it into the desired format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved my question by remapping my hash to a new array. Seems like it might be possible to do this with an original query, but I am not strong on Activerecord/SQL to make it happen.

Here is how I remapped the hash to an array of objects that could be used with D3-generator in Ruby

```
@referral_source = Client.count(:all, :group => :referral_source)
remap = @referral_source.map {|k, v| { Name: k, Count: v} } 

=> {{:Name=>"Internet search (e.g., Google)?", :Count=>26}, ... ]
```

Then I did a .to_json on that in the view. It took me a lot longer than I thought it would to figure out.